# Do AWS budgets have any hidden costs associated with them?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The AWS documentation says that setting 
a budget costs 0.02$/day. Do AWS budgets not make use of the cost explorer services? Making a request to the cost explorer API costs 0.01$ and I was wondering if the budgets make use of the cost explorer services which in turn would end up with me incurring additional costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/pricing/), the pricing for budgets is $0.02/day per budget, with Your first two budgets being free.

There are no additional charges for using the `budgets` feature of the Cost Management service, however, if you build a service or feature or function that uses `budgets` combined with any other service, such as the `Cost Explorer API`, then you would incur usage charges for both services.

As a general rule, AWS pricing is clear and transparent. AWS will typically notify you if you are launching a service that will incur additional charges as a result of other services that will be used and are required as part of the service you are launching.

Comment: Hmmm..... Assuming that AWS budgets make use of the cost explorer services to monitor the spend incurred by a user and considering the fact that budgets cost 0.02$/day, why does each request to the cost explorer cost 0.01$? Is it not overpriced? All I'm asking AWS is to show me the split up of the costs that I have incurred.

Comment: Even if `budgets` makes use of the `cost explorer` API behind the scenes, they're offered to users as two different services with different purposes/use cases. `Budgets` sends you alerts for chargers incurred either at an account level (ie total bill), or alternatively at usage level for certain services (eg EC2, DDB, S3 and RDS). The `Cost Explorer API` allows you to query the `Cost Management` service for granular data, like write operations on a specific DDB table.